# Processing HTTP GET request with Slim framework and JavaScript, (null) being called instead of GET

Tags: php, jquery, http, neo4j, get

I am buliding a simple web application with the Slim framework for manipulating family trees, using a Neo4j graph database.

The database is stored at Neo4j Aura and not locally, while the app is supposed to be running on my `localhost`. I am using the following project: https://github.com/neo4j-examples/movies-php-client as an example and trying to recreate everything the author of the mentioned project did with my use case.

I have encountered a problem while trying to list data from the database into my `index.html`. It appears that the GET method is not being called, as the output in the terminal, while running the app, is something like

`[Thu Jun 16 08:53:21 2022] 127.0.0.1:38344 [200]: (null) /people`

instead of

`[Thu Jun 16 08:53:21 2022] 127.0.0.1:38344 [200]: GET /people`

Here are the code snippets I think are important:

In `index.php` I have

```
<?php

/*importing libraries*/
/*database connection stuff*/

$app = AppFactory::create();
$app->addRoutingMiddleware();
$errorMiddleware = $app->addErrorMiddleware(true, true, true);

$app->get('/', static function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $response->getBody()->write(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/public/index.html'));
    return $response;
});

$app->get('/people', static function (Request $request, Response $response) use ($client) {
    $result = $client->run(<<<'CYPHER'
        MATCH (p:Person)
        RETURN  p.personID AS personID,
                p.firstName AS firstname,
                p.lastName AS lastName,
                p.birthDate AS birthDate,
                p.gender AS gender
        CYPHER);
    
    $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($result->getResults(), JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR));
    return $response;
});
?>
```

and this is `public/index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <title>Family trees</title>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function() {
        console.log("document is ready");
        $.get('/people', function(data, status, xhr) {
            console.log("I was here");
            if(!data) {
                console.log("no data");
                return;
            }
            for(const d of data) {
                console.log(d.firstName);
            }
        }, "json");
        console.log("passed .get");
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

After running this, I get the above mentioned `... (null) /people` in terminal and the only logs in the console are

> document is ready

and

> passed .get

This tells me that the problem occurs with `jQuery.get`, however I am really not sure anymore. I would appreciate any help as I am pretty new to using both the Slim framework and jQuery.

Comment: Hi @mirnana, can you show the request-response in the browser network tab as well? It might contain useful errors. Be sure to check the response body and actual status code

Answer (score 0):

`$.get('/people',` is relative path and you should access your index.html in webbrowser from apache/nginx instance and not directly as file. If you do and problem persist, try to set host url for relative paths with `<base>` tag.